# nsIProtocol Example Unclear

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I was comparing this example on MDN:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIProtocolHandler#Implementation

To this add-on on how to create custom protocol:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/files/browse/141969/file/components/AboutFosdem.js#top

Can someone please detail what exactly it's trying to do. The SMTP stuff threw me off.

I couldn't understand what that example on MDN is doing, its doing it whatever its doing without a chrome.manifst. I know the add-on is creating "fosdem://blah" where blah is whatever I want based on the definitions in `WhereToGo` but it uses a chrome.manifest.

I'm thinking that the mdn example is doing same thing as addon and I would do something like this to set my custom protocol after copy pasting that mdn code:

```
function myCustomBlah() {}

myCustomBlah.prototype =
  makeProtocolHandler("mycustomblah",
                      -1,
                      "b14c2b67-8680-4c11-8d63-9403c7d4f757"); //i can generate any id

var components = [myCustomBlah];
const NSGetFactory = XPCOMUtils.generateNSGetFactory(components);
```

Comment: @noitidart copying stuff into the *wiki* without any explanation whatsoever. :p

Comment: Who's noitidart? :P I think Im figuring this out as I read it more :P but they dont show how to properly uninstall it.

Comment: JFYI, I reverted the MDN edit. "Adding a mostly useless example that doesn't explain anything at all and uses interfaces only present in comm-central doesn't really help.".  While it is certainly a welcome and good thing to improve the wiki, the edits should actually be improvements and not just add to the confusion.

Comment: Ah I see I just checked the history of that MDN page and the guy that added that confusing example was noit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alrighty lets give a more sensible example of a custom protocol handler.

I decided to implement a `ddg:` protocol handler, that once registered can be used to type `ddg:some search terms` into the address bar (among other things) and it will load the DuckDuckGo search page for "some search terms".

#### The component

One needs to implement the [`nsIProtocolHandler`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIProtocolHandler) interface.

What this example component does is "redirect" to DuckDuckGo (well, not really redirect, but it returns a channel for duckduckgo.com). See comments inline.

```
var {classes: Cc,
     interfaces: Ci,
     manager: Cm,
     results: Cr,
     Constructor: CC
    } = Components;
Cm.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIComponentRegistrar);

Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/XPCOMUtils.jsm");

const SCHEME = "ddg";
const DDG_URI = Services.io.newURI("https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%s", null, null);

const nsIURI = CC("@mozilla.org/network/simple-uri;1", "nsIURI");

function DuckDuckGoProtocolHandler() {}
DuckDuckGoProtocolHandler.prototype = Object.freeze({
  classDescription: "DuckDuckGo Protocol Handler",
  contractID: "@mozilla.org/network/protocol;1?name=" + SCHEME,
  classID: Components.ID('{858ea860-129a-11e4-9191-0800200c9a66}'),
  QueryInterface: XPCOMUtils.generateQI([Ci.nsIProtocolHandler]),

  // nsIProtocolHandler
  scheme: SCHEME,
  defaultPort: -1, // No default port.

  // nsIProtocolHandler
  allowPort: function(port, scheme) {
    // This protocol handler does not support ports.
    return false;
  },

  // nsIProtocolHandler
  // Our protocol handler does not support authentication,
  // but it is OK to be loaded from any web-page, not just privileged pages""
  protocolFlags: Ci.nsIProtocolHandler.URI_NOAUTH |
                 Ci.nsIProtocolHandler.URI_LOADABLE_BY_ANYONE,

  // nsIProtocolHandler
  newURI: function(aSpec, aOriginCharset, aBaseURI) {
    // Nothing special here, actually. We were asked to create a new URI.

    // If there is a base-URI, this means that the browser tries to resolve
    // a dependent resource (an image, script) or the user clicked on a relative link.
    // In this case we cannot really return another "ddg" URI, but need to return
    // the proper https URI.
    if (aBaseURI && aBaseURI.scheme == SCHEME) {
      return Services.io.newURI(aSpec, aOriginCharset, DDG_URI);
    }

    // We don't care about the charset, so just ignore that
    // (we support what nsIURI supports).
    let rv = new nsIURI();
    rv.spec = aSpec;
    return rv;
  },

  // nsIProtocolHandler
  newChannel: function(aURI) {
    // We were asked to open a new channel.
    // We could implement an entirely custom channel that supports
    // (most of) nsIChannel. But that is tremendous work and outside
    // of the scope of this basic example (which is about protocol handlers and
    // not channels).
    // Or we can just return any other channel we can create.
    // Since we're going to implement the "ddg:" protocol, lets just open a
    // regular https channel to duckduckgo.com, use the URI as the search term
    // and return that channel.
    let spec = DDG_URI.spec.replace("%s", aURI.path);
    let channel = Services.io.newChannel(spec, aURI.originCharset, null);

    // Setting .originalURI will not only let other code know where this
    // originally came from, but the UI will actually show that .originalURI.
    channel.originalURI = aURI;

    return channel;
  }
});
```

#### Component registration in chrome.manifest

We need to implement `NSGetFactory` if our component is a JavaScript component
registered via chrome.manifest. Luckily, `XPCOMUtils.jsm` has a helper for that.

```
var NSGetFactory =
  XPCOMUtils.generateNSGetFactory([DuckDuckGoProtocolHandler]);
```

#### Registration in bootstrapped add-ons (and Scratchpad)

In bootstrapped/restartless add-ons (incl. SDK add-ons) and Scratchpad, one will need to register the component manually, as `chrome.manifest` registration is not available.

One could register the result of `NSGetFactory(classID)`, but here is some code creating a Factory manually and registering it.

```
function Factory(component) {
  this.createInstance = function(outer, iid) {
    if (outer) {
      throw Cr.NS_ERROR_NO_AGGREGATION;
    }
    return new component();
  };
  this.register = function() {
    Cm.registerFactory(component.prototype.classID,
                       component.prototype.classDescription,
                       component.prototype.contractID,
                       this);
  };
  this.unregister = function() {
    Cm.unregisterFactory(component.prototype.classID, this);
  }
    Object.freeze(this);
  this.register();
}
var factory = new Factory(DuckDuckGoProtocolHandler);
```

Please note that in restartless add-ons you'll also need to unregister it
again on shutdown!

```
factory.unregister();
```

#### Testing in a Scratchpad

Copy the component code and the manual registration code into a scratchpad, set the Enviroment to Browser, and run it. Then open `ddg:some search terms` in a tab ;)

[image: It works!]

Comment: Much cleaner than even my revised example. I rely on `unloaders` array. But you don't have support for `port` in this. I'm not sure what it does but moz comm central had it.

Comment: What exactly in your code prevents the URI from changing to `https://duckduckgo.com/?q=` plus search terms. My code changes the url to `twitter.com/` plus search terms. :( I thought it was setting `channel.originalURI` which I did, but still twitter uri takes over :(

Comment: Twitter likely does a regular http redirect or meta-refresh at some point.

Comment: You're right. I should implement the remaining `nsIProtocolHandler` attributes and methods I omitted out of lazyness. :p

Comment: Oh i'm not even sure if I got them all, I just tried to make sense of what I posted before and they had this `allowPort` thing haha :D i noticed about addons memory had this `getURIFlags` do we need that? actually now htat you menationed remaining nsIProtocolHandler, ill go lookup that interface and see if it has it. Oh answered it: [nsIAboutModule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIAboutModule) component has it tahts why we needed it.

Comment: Ah twitter doing the redirect is probably it, the only way to prevent that is using observer service huh? And all kind of yuck?

Comment: [about:addons-memory](https://github.com/nmaier/about-addons-memory) does not implement a protocol handler, just an about module (which is a tiny bit easier to implement and gives `about:something` URLs). PS: I added the remaining stuff now.

Comment: O i notice you make it return false. In my version i make it `return port == aDefaultPort;`. How do i know which way is right, because mxr doesnt have anything really on it: [nsIProtocolHandler.idl #allowPort](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/netwerk/base/public/nsIProtocolHandler.idl#77).What i mean is  I know yours doesnt implement, but mine does, so how do i know if i did it right? :P

Comment: If in doubt, I'm always right :p Actually, it doesn't matter what you return since that method shoul never be called anyway. The protocol handler does not support ports, after all.

Comment: Hey man why did you `Object.freeze` it? I know it makes it"immutable" but what was the point of that?

Answer (score 1):

Aw dang you beat me to it.

I totally understand about that removal from MDN.

I wrote this example, it has one problem, it changes the URL. I'll read your solution and compare to mine.

btw I lifted this from [about:addons-memory](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/about-addons-memory/) addon. In this example, if you type in `somecustomblah:noitidart`. it will take you to twitter.com/noitidart. The problem is, the url changes from `somecustomblah:noitidart` to `twitter.com/Noitidart/`, ill try to fix, i think your solution might have the answer @nmaier. This way doesn't require `chrome.manifest` and also you can register it with `reigsterComponents` and unregister it with `unregisterComponents`.

Make sure to generate your own UUID per your protocol: http://www.famkruithof.net/uuid/uuidgen

A third argument of `aDefaultPort` allows you to do that SMTP thing that moz central was doing. You can omit it, or make it null or undefined if you don't want to do that SMTP thing whree you use ports.

```
var {classes: Cc, interfaces: Ci, utils: Cu, results: Cr, manager: Cm} = Components; //can make this const if not in scratchpad
Cm.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIComponentRegistrar);
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm');
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/XPCOMUtils.jsm');

var nsIProtocolHandler = Ci.nsIProtocolHandler; //const

var unloaders = [];

function makeProtocolHandler(aProtocol, aClassID, aDefaultPort) {
    var obj = {
        classID: Components.ID(aClassID),
        classDescription: 'blah blah blah',
        contractID: '@mozilla.org/network/protocol;1?name=' + aProtocol,
        QueryInterface: XPCOMUtils.generateQI([nsIProtocolHandler]),
        scheme: aProtocol,
        defaultPort: aDefaultPort,
        protocolFlags: nsIProtocolHandler.URI_NORELATIVE | nsIProtocolHandler.URI_NOAUTH | nsIProtocolHandler.URI_LOADABLE_BY_ANYONE, //You must specify either URI_LOADABLE_BY_ANYONE, URI_DANGEROUS_TO_LOAD, URI_IS_UI_RESOURCE, or URI_IS_LOCAL_FILE in order for your protocol to work.
        newURI: function(aSpec, aOriginCharset, aBaseURI) {
            var uri = Cc['@mozilla.org/network/simple-uri;1'].createInstance(Ci.nsIURI);
            uri.spec = aSpec;
            console.log('uri=', uri);
            return uri;
        },

        newChannel: function(aURI) {
            //throw Cr.NS_ERROR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED;
            /* Get twitterName from URL */
            var postProtocolPath = aURI.spec.split(":")[1];
            var uri = Services.io.newURI("http://twitter.com/" + postProtocolPath, null, null);
            var channel = Services.io.newChannelFromURI(uri); //, null).QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHttpChannel); //i dont think i need to QI nsIHttpChannel
            /* Determines whether the URL bar changes to the URL */
            //channel.setRequestHeader("X-Moz-Is-Feed", "1", false);
            channel.originalURI = aURI;
            return channel;
        },
        getURIFlags: function(aURI) 0 // i dont think i need this? do I?
    };

    if (aDefaultPort == undefined || aDefaultPort == null) {
        aDefaultPort = -1;
    } else {
        obj.allowPort = function(port, scheme) {
            return port == aDefaultPort;
        };
    }

    return obj;
}

var myComponents = [myCustomBlah];

function myCustomBlah() {}
myCustomBlah.prototype = makeProtocolHandler('mycustomblah', 'b14c2b67-8680-4c11-8d63-9403c7d4f757'); //this uuid (2nd argument) should be generated by you from here: http://www.famkruithof.net/uuid/uuidgen

//const NSGetFactory = XPCOMUtils.generateNSGetFactory(components);


function registerComponents() {
    for (let [y, cls] in Iterator(myComponents)) {
        console.info('y: ', y, 'cls: ', cls);
        try {
            var factory = {
                _cls: cls,
                createInstance: function(outer, iid) {
                    if (outer) {
                        throw Cr.NS_ERROR_NO_AGGREGATION;
                    }
                    return new cls();
                }
            };
            Cm.registerFactory(cls.prototype.classID, cls.prototype.classDescription, cls.prototype.contractID, factory);
            unloaders.push(function() {
                Cm.unregisterFactory(factory._cls.prototype.classID, factory);
            });
        } catch (ex) {
            console.warn('failed to register module: ', cls.name, 'exception thrown: ', ex);
        }
    }
}

function unregisterComponents() {
    for (var i = 0; i < unloaders.length; i++) {
        unloaders[i]();
    }
}

registerComponents(); //run this to make it work. once this is run follwoing examples above: typing "about:yabba" will take you to bings homepage
//unregisterComponents(); //do this to remove it //after running this typing about:yabba will take you to problem loading page
```

Comment: :D :D its what blagoh used so i was just catering to him :P i felt bad for confusing the fellow :P