# firefox addon: set new tab url as buildin app page

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, jackrabbit

I want to make a Firefox addon that will open an web app I build myself when I open a new tab.
I'm using firefox add on sdk so I put the app files in the addon data page.

The thing is it can open the app index.html page as I expected, But in index.html I include some css and js files like jquery, all files are in the same package. then all the css and js file can not be loaded, while images can be loaded.

Anyone knows how to access this files? thanks.

Comment: Recommendation instead of .html do .xhtml so you can localize it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Bootstrapped_extensions#XUL_and_HTML_Files_-_Using_Entities_from_DTD_Files

Comment: html should work fine in an SDK addon. CSS and JS files should load normally if linked to correctly. Can you show us your folder structure, the HTML code that links to the other files, and the network requests in the console? Does the webapp open normally if you just open the HTML file directly in the browser?

Comment: my app is built with normal html, css and js files, all located in the data folder of the Firefox addon sdk project. the app works fine if I open it directly in the browser.

Comment: It make is hard to help if you don't have a simple code example to see what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

This is a non-sdk (so its a pure bootstrap) solution:

Download this addon: [Github Extension Installer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/github-extension-installer/) this addon adds a "Add to Firefox" button to github repos that are repos of firefox-addons.

Go to this repo: https://github.com/Noitidart/l10n/tree/xhtml-xul

Click "Add to Firefox"

It will open up an xhtml page and an xul page. your app you should either one of those. xhtml allows you to use html for everything. xul means you need xul instead of html, although you can still use html just have to namespace it.

this demo shows how to do so with localization.

if you want to make your app url be "about:hanks-app" or something like that then create the "about:hanks-app" and set the direction to your "chrome://l10n/content/my.xul" or whatever pgae you make. To see how to make "about" urls see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24919721/1828637