# Create Protocol Handler in firefox addon sdk

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I want to create an extension with a protocol handler using firfox addon-sdk. So that if i do shan:something it should redirect to some other url like (www.google.com).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24917460/nsiprotocol-example-unclear

Comment: Hey Thanks. But i face a problem out of it. It works fine on scratchpad but on do the same using addon-sdk it throws error.

Answer (score 2):

To access `Components`, i.e. features outside the the SDK modules you will need to use [`require("chrome")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Chrome_Authority) to import those capabilities.

The rest is already covered by [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24917460/nsiprotocol-example-unclear) that @noitdart linked.

Comment: Hey Thanks man. Error I made was, I used 'Cc' for calling a constructor instead of 'CC'. After changing it 'nsIUrl' variable (from the example) declaration from Cc to CC it works fine for me.